# MySQL query results with weekday between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, date

I need a query to get results from a table that has 2 columns

Column startdt (datetime), Column enddt (datetime)
there are some records with startdt 2013-07-19 and enddt 2013-07-29

I need to get the records with weekday = 1 (Tuesday)
the record with date 2013-07-19 is weekday 4 and ends 2013-07-29 which is 0

Actually i want to get the results that has for weekday Monday or another weekday.

You can check the above link for an example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80ce/1

If you don't understand what i want to do let me explain. I have an event that starts July 15 and ends July 25. (Starts Monday and ends Thursday) The user selects one of the week days (Monday, Tuesday etc). If he select Tuesday then i want the query that will get all events that are active in Tuesday.

I already found the answer so if anyone want to check it

```
SELECT articleid,startdt,enddt,dayofweek(startdt), DATEDIFF(enddt,startdt) datedf 
FROM events 
WHERE (dayofweek(events.startdt) <= 3 AND dayofweek(events.enddt) >= 3)
OR DATEDIFF(enddt,startdt) >=6
```

(3 is the number of the weekday "Tuesday")

Comment: Have you looked into MySQL's [`DAYNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname), [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) and [`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) functions?

Comment: i already looked at weekday() function
If u execute this query 
SELECT ArticleID,startdt,enddt,weekday(startdt) as weekst,weekday(enddt) as weeknd FROM events
Example: i want the records that has like weekday 3 which is Thursday

Comment: So add a filter: e.g. `... WHERE WEEKDAY(column) = 3`

Comment: i can't add that filter because the 3 is between 2 dates
if i have the start date July 15 2013 and the end date July 25 2013
the weekday for the start date is 0 and for end date is 3
if i want to search for 2 there will be no results.
I want to get all events that will be active for the weekday thursday

Comment: I already edited the question so you can understand what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the comments that other people gave you and use a query that combines both `dayofweek` and a simple greater/smaller/equal syntax as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM events where dayofweek(events.startdt) <= 6 AND dayofweek(events.enddt) >= 6
```

This gives the following results if the user specified a friday (= 6):

```
ARTICLEID   STARTDT     ENDDT
4   July, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000     July, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000
6   July, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000     July, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

I do think that you are better of using `dayofmonth` however as this (maybe just to me) makes it clearer, possibly combining the use of both to ensure that it's active on a friday.

The OP indicates that events which are in the history should also be retrieved and as such the following query does what he wants:

```
SELECT * FROM events where dayofweek(events.startdt) <= 6 AND dayofweek(events.enddt) >= 6 OR DATEDIFF(enddt,startdt) >=6
```

Comment: I already did that and the results are not what i want. You can check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80ce/38
I selected 3 for Tuesday and the results should be ID 1,2,3,4,6 and not only ID 6 because Tuesday is between all the dates except ID 5

Comment: I am quite confused, do you want all the events active on the date the user selected or do you want all events that are active on the day of the week that the user selected. Let's assume the user selects tuesday, july 23 what events should he see?

Comment: I want all the events that are active Tuesday (only Tuesday) and not specific date.
I made this query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80ce/51 and i think is ok. I used the DATEDIFF to calculate the difference between 2 dates and if the difference is >= 6 then will show the record.

Comment: Just no... that is a very bad and flawed idea. Add '('2013-02-01 00:00:00','2013-05-01 00:00:00')' to your schema and your query will pick it up as well. You have to use a combination of `dayofmonth` with `dayofweek`. I want to stress again that your question is still unclear, what does 'active' on 'only tuesday' mean because your query also selects events in history.

Comment: I just added the new record and the results were ok.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c19e2/1
i just want to check if Tuesday or another day is one of the days that the event is active. If the event is active from Monday July 15 2013 to Friday July 19 2013 and the user click on Tuesday then he will see this event because Tuesday is between Monday and Friday.
After i will use this query to get featured events or past events.
Is something like i want to go to an event and i'm able to go there only Friday and i want to see all events that will be active on Friday.

Comment: So you also want to see events that are in the past? I don't really see the logic in that since you can't physically attend those events anymore.

Comment: The whole thing with the events is for someone to check in to events that someone else has created. If he goes to his history he can see the events he went. I will not use the filtering with week day for past events. I will use it for upcoming events.
Thank you again for your help and inspiration. :)

Comment: Then the addition that you did to my answer is sufficient yes, I will update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

- first you convert the day of week in format that 6 is Saturday and 7 is sunday(it's easier for me)

  if(dayofweek(o.start_date) = 1, 7, dayofweek(o.start_date) -1)
- after that you calc the days from the start_date needed to reach some of the weekdays

  (7 - if(dayofweek(o.start_date) = 1, 7, dayofweek(o.start_date) -1)
- finally you make sure that the difference in days between the two dates is no less that the above calculation

  (7 - if(dayofweek(o.start_date) = 1, 7, dayofweek(o.start_date) -1) <= datediff(o.end_date, o.start_date)